# Uniformly Most Poweful Hypothesis test for the difference between two means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have data for two groups, $G_1$ of n trials and $G_2$ of m trials, of which datasets $x_1$ and $x_2$ have been collected. These can be binomially distributed, $X_1$ ~ B(n,p), $X_2$ ~ B(m,q).

I would like to test the hypotheses $H_0 : p=q$ vs. $H_1 : p\not=q$. This looks to me like a t-test but I would like to find a test statistic which is uniformly most powerful, and show that it is equivalent to the Neyman Pearson test statistic, $\prod  f_n(x;p)/{f_m(x,q)} $, although I don't see how it can be applied to two datasets. Do I need to use a different approach, such as a confidence interval for the maximum likelihood estimator?

Or a Pearson chi-squared test?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand the relevance of the Fisher information for just one of the groups. Isn't the problem perfectly symmetrical in the groups?  Are you trying to suggest there is some inherent asymmetry?

Comment: I'll remove the fisher information, I assume it isn't relevant. I'm not suggesting asymmetry, I just don't understand how to formulate the UMP hypothesis test with a p-value and critical region. :(